# Why is my php/mysql update not accurate?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a webpage with a button on it. When the button it clicked it sends a request to a page with this code on it

```
$userName = "tdscott";
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$divID = explode('?', $url);
$id = 0;
$id = explode('@',$divID[1])[1];



$func = $divID[2];
$find = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT likes FROM status WHERE id='$id'"))['likes'];

if ($func == "addLike")
{

$promoted = $userName . "-";
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE status SET promotedBy = CONCAT(promotedBy,'$promoted') WHERE id='$id'");

$find++;
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE status SET likes = '$find' WHERE id='$id'");
echo $find;


}//end if addLike
elseif($func === "removeLike")
{
 echo "ERROR";
}//end if removeLike
elseif ($func === "getLikes")
{
echo $find;
}//end if getLikes


mysqli_close($con);
```

I left of the database connection information. But for some reason when this is called it produces inaccurate results. For example... Sometimes it will put multiple instances of `$promoted` in the promotedBy field in my table and sometimes it will update other rows in the table that the id does not equal the current `$id`. I am wondering if somehow it is getting the `$id` variable mixed up from when I submitted it with a different value before. Is there a way to reset the variables before I call it each time?

Please note: In the if statement, we are only looking at the `addLike` portion. I included the other just in case it was causing the problem.

Comment: It cannot be retaining values between calls. But there are other problems here: (1) code is vulnerable to SQL injection; (2) odd use of explode to parse parameters from the URL, instead of `$_GET` / `$_POST`; (3) use of a GET request instead of a POST request to perform a mutative action on the server; (4) no anti-CSRF token to prevent form spoofing; (5) storing multiple values concatenated in a single DB field (promotedBy) is not best practice; (6) getting & setting the `likes` count in two separate requests, so that it will become incorrect if updated by multiple requests simultaneously

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
unset($id);
```

Sorry should have done more research.

Comment: This will have absolutely no effect on anything.

Comment: It fixed the problem I was having. it was because my browser was reading earlier versions of the id variable.

Comment: @user2930376 your browser, actually, have not a slightest idea on the id variable.

Comment: Correction... server*

Comment: I'll say it again then: This will have absolutely no effect on anything. Variable values are not retained between requests.